# Foursquare photo upload using rest-client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foursquare, rest-client

I'm trying to upload a photo for a venue using the following request using [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client):

```
url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/photos/add"
payload = {"venueId"=><venueId>, "v"=><api version>, "oauth_token"=> oauth_token}
    
RestClient.post(url, payload, content_type: 'image/jpeg', :upload => {file: File.new(file, "rb")})
```

The response I keep getting is:

`400 Bad Request: {"meta":{"code":400,"errorType":"other","errorDetail":"Missing file upload","requestId":"5785e24f498e5d2c551de22b"},"notifications":[{"type":"notificationTray","item":{"unreadCount":0}}],"response":{}}`

The request that is being sent out is:

`RestClient.post "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/photos/add", "venueId=xxxxxxxx&v=xxxxxx&oauth_token=xxxxxx", "Accept"=>"*/*; q=0.5, application/xml", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate", "Content-Length"=>"104", "Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Upload"=>"{:file=>#<File:/tmp/location_photos/2c07b63affc74e5ba6c2e232beb43a05.jpg>}"`

I'm unable to move past this step. Should I look into other http clients or is there a way I can get this done using rest-client itself? Thanks in advance. Cheers!

**update**

I tried the same in `Net::HTTP` with `http.set_debug_output($stdout)`.
I have pasted the response in a gist(was unable to format the response here. :3). You can access the gist here: `https://gist.github.com/ananth99/86381b37594df969b0f0c2911d7d7a69`

Comment: Wild hunch - can you try `RestClient.post(url, payload, content_type: 'image/jpeg', file: File.new(file, "rb")})` ?

Comment: @IleEftimov Getting `"{\"meta\":{\"code\":400,\"errorType\":\"invalid_auth\",\"errorDetail\":\"Missing access credentials. See https:\\/\\/developer.foursquare.com\\/docs\\/oauth.html for details.\"},\"response\":{}}"` as the response.I'm guessing the oauth_token is going as a part of the headers instead of query params? Don't know.

Debugging it with Net::HTTP with set_debug_output. Will update once I get the data.